# read files from folders and its subfolders and convert into one property file java

Tags: java, json, java-8, properties-file

I want to read folders and subfolders from resource folder and convert all json files from folders and its subfolders into one property file.

resource folder will contain only json files.

Below code is to read files from resource folder. **resources/channel/sms**

Inside channel, I have different folder like mms, chat etc..

Someone, please help me to read all json files from folders and its subfolders and convert them into one property file.

```
 public void loadFile() throws IOException {
    String folder = "/channel/sms";
    List<String> files = IOUtils.readLines(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(folder), Charsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(JSONUtil.toJSON(files));         
 }
```

Can someone help me to convert JSON files to property file.
Json **file name** should be **key** and **value** should be its **file value.**

Example :

**helloWorld.json**

```
{
    "KEY1": {
        "KEY2": "Hello"
    },
    "KEY3":"World"
}
```

Property file should be:

```
helloWorld = { "KEY1": { "KEY2": "Hello"}, "KEY3":"World"}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code,i tested it successfully

here our json files inside folder (D://test//)

our one properties file path (D:\properties\property.properties)

```
package com.pms.lot;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

/*sibin*/
 public class CustomTest {

public static void main(String ard[]) {

    /* Function to get File Name */
    File folder = new File("D://test");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            String basename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
            try {
                byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D://test//" + listOfFiles[i].getName()));
                String str = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                System.out.println(basename + "=" + str);

                // Insertion

                /* create text file and insert text */

                String fileNames = "D:\\properties\\property.properties";

                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                FileWriter fw = null;

                try {

                    String content = basename + "=" + str;

                    fw = new FileWriter(fileNames,true);
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(content);

                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    try {

                        if (bw != null)
                            bw.close();

                        if (fw != null)
                            fw.close();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
    /**/

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here i am using **Java 8**

Working Code Snippet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFiles {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("parent"))) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(ReadFiles::convert);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void convert(Path name) {
        try {
            // using java 8
            Path output = Paths.get("property.properties");
            // read json file from all folder and subfolder and make a single
            // line string
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(name.toUri()))).replaceAll("[\t\r\n]", "");
            // append filename
            String str = name.getFileName() + "= " + content + "\n";
            // write into properties file
            Files.write(output, str.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Folder Structure

[image: This is my folder structure]

Here is Output properties file

```
helloword.json= {"KEY1": {"KEY2": "Hello"},"KEY3": "World"} 
hellowordparent.json= {"Details": {"Name": "Dhiraj"},"Surname": "Pandit"}
```